# How to preserve the previous row values when a new row is added to asp grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp grid where data is dynamically binded. To same grid I add a new row with textbox. The problem is that adding another new row doesn't preserve the previous row data.

Here is the grid structure and code.

ASPX CODE HERE :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReceivedComponent" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="searchResultHeader" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="searchResultRow" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="searchResultAltRow" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItemRetComp" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Component #">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblgvModel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MODELNO") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtModel" Width="85px" MaxLength="20" onkeypress="uppercase();" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowModel" CssClass="searchbutton" Width="20px" Text="..." ToolTip="Search for Model" />
                <input type="hidden" id="hdnModelDesc" runat="server" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="hdnModelIdy" runat="server" value="0" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Component Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblgvModelDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MODELDESC") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" BOM Qty">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="width: 20px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblgvBOMRecvCompQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QTY") %>'></asp:Label></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actual Qty" HeaderStyle-Width="90px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtActRecvCompQty" Width="30px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QTY") %>' onkeypress="return IsNumeric()" onKeyDown="javascript:return ResetRCompChkBox(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFlagtohidegvControls" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ISNEW")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# CODE HERE :

```
void gvReceivedComponent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btnShowModel = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnShowModel");
            TextBox txtModel = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtModel");
            TextBox txtModelDesc = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtModelDesc");
            HtmlInputHidden hdnModelDesc = (HtmlInputHidden)e.Row.FindControl("hdnModelDesc");
            HtmlInputHidden hdnModelIdy = (HtmlInputHidden)e.Row.FindControl("hdnModelIdy");
            HiddenField hdnFlagtohidegvControls = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnFlagtohidegvControls");

            btnShowModel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ShowDivPopup('" + Constants.LookupCategory.CLIENTCUSTOMERMODEL + "', '" + Constants.LookupCategorySearchParms.CLIENTCUSTOMERMODELSEARCH + "', '" + txtModel.ClientID + "', '" + txtModelDesc.ClientID + "', 'false', '" + frmRecvRepairs.ID + "', '3','" + hdnModelIdy.ClientID + "');");

            if (hdnFlagtohidegvControls.Value == "Y")
            {
                txtModel.Visible = false;
                txtModelDesc.Visible = false;
                btnShowModel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                txtModel.Visible = true;
                txtModelDesc.Visible = true;
                btnShowModel.Visible = true;
            }

        }

    }
```

> Binding the grid

```
if (dsRAComponent != null)
        {
            if (dsRAComponent.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                dsRAComponent.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ISNEW"));
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsRAComponent.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    dr["ISNEW"] = "Y";
                }
                if (dsRAComponent.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gvReceivedComponent.DataSource = dsRAComponent;
                    gvReceivedComponent.DataBind();
                }
                Session["dsRAComponent"] = dsRAComponent.Tables[0];
            }
```

Add new row

```
 if (Session["dsRAComponent"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["dsRAComponent"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow;
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["MODELNO"] = String.Empty;
            drCurrentRow["MODELDESC"] = String.Empty;
            drCurrentRow["QTY"] = 0;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.InsertAt(drCurrentRow, 0);
            Session["dsRAComponent"] = dtCurrentTable;
            //Rebind the Grid with the current data
            gvReceivedComponent.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            gvReceivedComponent.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you placing your rebinding code

Comment: @Jags The dataset is stored in session and while adding the new row on button click('Add new row') a new row is added.

Comment: Add you are sure that your datatable in session has all the existing rows available...dubugged and checked ?

Comment: The dataset doesn't have entered values of rows.

Answer (score 0):

In pagelod event are you binding data by checking !IsPostBack ?
Try to bind it everytime.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewState property to preserve the previous data.
Check this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-data-in-GridView-without-using-database-in-ASPNet.aspx)